# Accidentally deleted OS X partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, dual-boot

I was installing Windows 7 using bootcamp on my iMac machine and accidentally deleted the main OS X partition while doing that. So now I when I start the machine I see only an option to choose windows during startup.

I had another drive within my OS X which I am unable to view now from my Windows machine when I go to the Disk Management.

Is there a way I could access that drive?

Comment: Did you try the restore function ?

Comment: Did you complete the install of Windows on Bootcamp and install the Apple Drivers? If so, Windows should be able to read and HFS+ volume.

Comment: When you say "I had another drive within my OS X" do you mean another hard drive installed in your iMac? Or did you have your single hard drive partitioned into two volumes?